# In google sheets, grab last (by row) value in range that meets criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We have this dummy spreadsheet. In cell A15, we want the last value from A1:A13 that meets the criteria `not equal to --, and not blank`. A15 should then be 43, and B15 should be 23. Pretty much we just need the last non-blank, non "--" value in the range.

[image]

Presumably this can be done with a nasty long, nested `ifelse` type of statement, but we'd like to avoid that. Is there a better solution? Edit - added column C with integer range as I think this may be of some help?

Answer (score 0):

try in A15:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MAX(ROW(A1:A13)*(A1:A13<>"")*(A1:A13<>"--"))))
```

alternative:

```
=QUERY(SORT(A1:A13, ROW(A1:A13), ), 
 "where Col1 is not null and Col1 <> '--' limit 1", )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in A15 and drag to the right:

```
=MATCH(9^9,A1:A13,1)
```

Comment: It gives "N/A" in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter this in A15 and drag to the right:

```
=regexextract(join("~",A1:A13),".*~(\d+)")
```

Edit: you can also do it with a single formula like this:
`=regexextract(regexreplace(substitute(join("#",query(A1:B13,,9^9))&"#"," ","~"),"[~-]+#","#"),regexreplace(regexreplace(substitute(join("#",query(A1:B13,,9^9))&"#"," ","~"),"[~-]+#","#"),"~(\d+)#","~($1)#"))`

[image]

You can adjust the two occurrences of `A1:B13` to cover a bigger range.